# Layouting JPanel inside JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout

i have some very little knowledge regarding GUIs on Java since im more on the backend not on the view side, so i am having a problem properly aligning and layouting stuff on the Jframe. Basically i wanted to have these result

[image]

The image speaks for itself already, but what i have when i run my code is this.

[image]

There is no padding on both ends, the panel is right smack on the border of the Jframe, which i want to correct, i don't want to have this kind of layout wherein the panel is of the same size as the Jframe, at least there would be somekind of padding on both ends.

here is my code though, this is on the constructor of my Frame

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    String[] cNames = {"First Name", "Middle Name","Last Name","Status"};
    Object[][] data = {{"John Doe", "John Doe", "John Doe", "Single"},
                       {"Doe John", "Doe John", "Doe John", "Married"}};
    JTable table = new JTable(data, cNames);
    table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));

    jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table);

    listPahel = new JPanel();
    listPahel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    listPahel.add(jScrollPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    add(listPahel);
```

The Above code reuslts into that 2nd image above

if you have any insights please do enlighten me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way would be to set a border on your `JPanel`:

```
listPahel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
```

Comment: exactly wat i need.. easy ang precise

Comment: hacking away ;-) Hard-coded _pixels_ are always problematic, in a border as much as in a size/location. Better (imo) use a layoutManager that allows fine-grained control in terms of dpi-related units ...

Answer (score 3):

1. add EmptyBorders to JPanel

   or
2. add empty JPanels (four) to the EAST, WEST, NORTH, SOUTH area of JFrame and JPanel with JScrollPane put to the CENTER area, then is created gap in 10pixels around CENTER area

   then to
3. change LayoutManager for JPanel contains JScrollPane from FlowLayout (default implemented in API) to BorderLayout